# what's the rewrite rule meaning?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1 [R=301,L]
```

what's the meaning of this line ( RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1 [R=301,L] ). thank you.

Comment: I think will crash your site, it will do an infinite loop

Comment: Ibu: But only if, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [301 (permanent) redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) from whatever path that is on to the relative domain name:

`http://<your website>.com/example.com` will redirect to `http://example.com`.

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1 [R=301,L]

It is literally saying, "Ok, everything found in this folder should be considered permanently redirected to that domain".

- `^(.*)$` means select everything and call it $1
- `http://$1` means Go to domain stored in $1
- `R=301` refers to [status code 301](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2), the "permanently moved" redirect.
- L means that this is the final instruction for anything matching that pattern. No other redirect rule *after* this one will effect these redirects.

Answer (score 1):

`$1`  is the `first` argument  in the rule given 
sameway `$2` is the `second` etc

Genrally it is used to take slug from your url

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

it will do like reditect `http://abc.com/post to`http://xyz.com/post`

301 - stands for permanent redirection 
L - shows that this is last rule to .htaccess

Comment: what's the meaning of slug? thank you

Comment: we can say something like unique indentification of a pafef...in above example `post` is a slug

Answer (score 0):

This specific rewrite rule will redirect the following URL:

```
http://site.com/anothersite.com
```

to..

```
http://anothersite.com/
```

.. with a status of 301, which means Permanent Redirection.

Comment: @Shef np, posted it before you removed yours I think (or at the same time!)

Answer (score -1):

You can learn about what [RewriteRules do inside the Apache Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html). I only write this, because the meaning of something is related to it's technical understanding.

If you are interested in what my meaning of the following is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's a redirect to another location in the internet, a permanent redirect. Test it, it works!